# Prove differentiablity of a piecewise function

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Prove that the following function is differentiable at $x=\frac{\pi}{4}$:

$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
-cosx + C_1,  & \text{x $\lt \frac{\pi}{4}$ } \\
sinx -\sqrt2 + C_1, & \text{x $\ge \frac{\pi}{4}$ }
\end{cases}$$

$C_1 \in \mathbb{R}$

I tried to solve it using definition of sided derivatives but got stuck on the algebra of calculating limits. I would appreciate if anyone could show me how it should be done. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For $x\in \mathbb{R}\setminus\{\frac{\pi}{4}\}$, it is clear that $f$ is continuous and differentiable.

You have to prove, then that 
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow \frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{f(x)-f(\frac{\pi}{4})}{x-\frac{\pi}{4}}$$
exists and is finite.

From the geometry of this problem, it is convenient to divide in two parts the work : prove that 
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow \frac{\pi}{4}^+} \frac{f(x)-f(\frac{\pi}{4})}{x-\frac{\pi}{4}} \qquad \text{and} \qquad \lim_{x\rightarrow \frac{\pi}{4}^-} \frac{f(x)-f(\frac{\pi}{4})}{x-\frac{\pi}{4}}$$
exists and are equal.

For the first one :
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow \frac{\pi}{4}^+} \frac{\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}-\cos(x)}{x-\frac{\pi}{4}}=\lim_{x\rightarrow \frac{\pi}{4}^+} \frac{\cos(\frac{\pi}{4})-\cos(x)}{x-\frac{\pi}{4}} =-(\cos')(\frac{\pi}{4})=\sin(\frac{\pi}{4})=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$$

Same method for the second one.

It is differentiable.

Comment: Thank you. However, that was my question. How can it be shown?

Comment: Did you use L'hopital?

Comment: @GalushBalush not a all! Just used the definition of the derivative of $\cos$ at the point $\frac{\pi}{4}$, so basically there is nothing to compute...

Comment: Thank you. One last question. Don't you have to show that the function is continuous? I mean, your method can work for $f(x) =
\begin{cases}
-cosx + 1,  & \text{x $\lt \frac{\pi}{4}$ } \\
sinx = 1, & \text{x $\ge \frac{\pi}{4}$ }
\end{cases}$ which is not differentiable at $x=\frac{\pi}{4}$

Comment: @GalushBalush no you don't have to, since a well-known theorem states that if $f$ is differentiable, it implies the continuity (you can do it if you want additionally, but it is unnecessary).

Answer (score 0):

$f\in C^1(\mathbb{R}/{\frac{\pi}{4}})$

In order for f to be in $C^1(\mathbb{R})$, the left and the right of function and derivative  must exist and be equal:

$f^+(\frac{\pi}{4})=C_1-\frac{2}{\sqrt{2}}\\
f^-=C_1-\frac{2}{\sqrt{2}}$

$f'^-(\frac{\pi}{4})=\sin(\frac{\pi}{4})=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\\
f'^+(\frac{\pi}{4})=\cos(\frac{\pi}{4})=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$

Thus $f\in C^1(\mathbb{R})$

Comment: How did you get to that conclusion? Is there a theorem stating that?

Comment: @GalushBalush for a direct method see my edit

Comment: @GalushBalush It's the same of Netchaiev, just "disguised"

Comment: @gabrielecassese not exactly the same, since I don't have to use a theorem of yours... as I said it is a direct method.

Comment: The property is true but **isn't** the same that the answer of Netchaiev disguised. See my answer.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla it uses the continuity of the derivative, and in that differs from netchayev's one. I used "disguised" and not disguised exactly for that point

Comment: @OK, I misunderstand you.

Answer (score 0):

This function is clearly continuous, the differentiability mean 
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow \frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{f(x)- f(\frac{\pi}{4})}{x- \frac{\pi}{4}}=\lim_{x \rightarrow \frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{f(x)+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}-C_1}{x- \frac{\pi}{4}} \text{ exist and finite  }       $$
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow^> \frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{f(x)+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}-C_1}{x- \frac{\pi}{4}} =\lim_{x \rightarrow^> \frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{-cos(x)+C_1+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}-C_1}{x- \frac{\pi}{4}} = \lim_{x \rightarrow^> \frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{-cos(x)+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}}{x- \frac{\pi}{4}}=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} $$
 from the derivative of $cos(x)$ at $ x=\frac{\pi}{4}$
in the other hand we have

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow^< \frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{f(x)+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}-C_1}{x- \frac{\pi}{4}} =\lim_{x \rightarrow^> \frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{sin(x)-\sqrt{2}+C_1+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}-C_1}{x- \frac{\pi}{4}} = \lim_{x \rightarrow^> \frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{sin(x)-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}}{x- \frac{\pi}{4}}=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} $$
by the same reason, is it okay?

Answer (score 0):

Theorem: Let be $f:(c - h, c + h)\longrightarrow\Bbb R$, $h > 0$ s.t.

- $f$ is continuous in $(c - h, c + h)$,
- $f$ is differentiable in $(c - h,c)\cup(c,c + h)$,
- exists $\lim_{x\to c}f'(x)$.

Then exists
$$f'(c) = \lim_{x\to c}f'(x).$$
Proof:

Take $x\in(c,c + h)$. Applying Rolle to $f$ in $[c,x]$,
$$\exists c_x\in(c,x):\qquad\frac{f(x) - f(c)}{x - c} = f'(c_x).$$ As $x\to c^+\implies c_x\to c$:
$$
f_+'(c) = \lim_{x\to c^+}\frac{f(x) - f(c)}{x - c} =
\lim_{x\to c^+}f'(c_x) = \lim_{x\to c}f'(x).
$$

Using the same argument in $(c - h,c)$,
$$
f_-'(c) = \lim_{x\to c}f'(x).
$$